# ViewController does not function with Assistant editor

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, assistant

I recently copied my project across and whilst it compiles and runs correctly (all outlets function) i noticed that the data types don't highlight on my @property in two of my .H files.

After fiddling around i noticed that the view does not seem to have the .H file associated with it so when i use assistant mode the 'Automatic' option fails to work it states, "No assistant rules".

The class in the "identity inspector" is correctly linked to the .H file but after looking at the XML for the storyboard i noticed this:

```
<viewController title="First" id="2" customClass="FirstViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

In comparison to the view controllers that work correctly having this XML

```
<viewController title="buttonView" id="YcW-az-POT" customClass="buttonViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

I get this impression that the ID field seems to be causing issues, has anyone else experienced this or do they know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very oddly, i committed my changes to my repository grabbed them on another device, then went back to the original device and pulled the changes made on the second device and the problem disappeared.

On further investigation it appeared to be as i initially suspected the ID was not correctly relating to the object. If you get this i suggest adding a new view and re-linking your content t the class implementation and it should resolve the issue.